# How to change default Content type of Wiki Library items in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, content-type, sharepoint-designer

I am working on a SharePoint 2010 Wiki Library. The items in the Wiki Library have a default content type 'Wiki Page'.

I have created my custom content type with some additional fields. I would like to change the default content type and assign my custom content type to existing items in Wiki Library i.e. from 'Wiki Page' to 'My Custom Content Type'

Please let me know how we can go about changing the content type in Wiki Library.

Any comment/feedback is greaatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Did you tried form user interface means from site? You deployed or created your content type for your site right!! Now goto **library settings** of that wiki page and change the content types of that page. See the below images.
[image]

After adding your content types, delete the old content types. So your new content type with specified fields will be appear. 
[image]

Hope you this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this resource, a wiki library is similar to a list in terms of dealing with content types:

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/13649/content-type-ordering-or-making-it-default-ct